# PHP: Update value start from 0 and not 1

Tags: php, sql

I have a table where I drag and drop, when I drop the row I want to update order values, it works but start updating from value 0 and I want start from 1.

Example before drag and drop:
[image]

After:

[image]

My code looks like here:

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request)
   {

       $queryParams = [];

       $ids = $request->ids;
       //el query será definido en su totalidad de forma manual
       $query = 'UPDATE projects SET `order` = CASE id ';
       //agregamos cada parámetro de orden y de id al array para respetar las convenciones de PDO
       foreach ($ids as $order => $id) {
           $query .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
           $queryParams[] = (int) $id;
           $queryParams[] = (int) $order;
       }


       //por último agregamos los ids implicados en el update
       $queryParams = array_merge($queryParams, $ids);

       //generamos los ? necesarios para el array de ids en el query PDO
       $whereInArray = array_fill(0, count($ids), '?');
       $whereInString = implode(", ", $whereInArray);

       //agregamos dicho string generado al query final
       $query .= "END WHERE id IN ($whereInString)";

       //realizamos el update
       DB::update($query, $queryParams);
   }
```

¿What I need to update in code?

Comment: Try `$queryParams[] = (int) $order+1;`

Comment: It works. Post like an answer :)

Comment: Really glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

Please try `$queryParams[] = (int) $order+1;`

Comment: Thanks, think this function should be passed to eloquent?

Comment: Please ask any questions whenever you got into stuck